# How to obtains count of entries in Table_A having X number of references in Table_B

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to make a query that count the number of item in A having at least 4 (>= 4) references in table  B according the schemas below:

```
Table_a
| ID | Content  |
|----|----------|
|  1 | some text|
|  2 | some text|
| ...| ...      |
```

```
Table_b

| ID | table_a_id  | content |
|----|-------------|---------|
|  1 | 1           | blabla  |
|  2 | 1           | blabla  |
|  3 | 1           | blabla  |
|  4 | 2           | blabla  |
|  5 | 2           | blabla  |
|  6 | 2           | blabla  |
|  7 | 2           | blabla  |
```

In this example, the query must return *1*

I have very little experience with sql and I'm just trying some things out. Thanks in advance for you help

Comment: Firstly, you've tagged your question with both MySQL and PSQL (which is the command-line tool for PostgreSQL). What database system are you actually using? Secondly, you'll generally get better responses here if you include a bit more detail of your problem, and what you've tried. Have a look at [ask], [mcve], and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can use an EXISTS condition for this:

```
select a.*
from table_a a
where exists (select 1
              from table_b b
              where b.table_a_id = a.id
              having count(*) >= 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want the count as well, you can put the subquery in the `from` clause:

```
select a.*, b.cnt
from table_a a join
     (select table_a_id, count(*) as cnt
      from table_b
      group by table_a_id
     ) b
     on b.table_a_id = a.id
where cnt >= 4;
```

If you have a large amount of data, it would be interesting to compare the performance of this solution with the correlated subquery solution.